# An Useful Result in Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a borelian, finite measure space, WLOG, $\mu(X)=a$.

Are there any additional hypotheses that guarantee the following assertion is true?

" For any real number $0\leq b <a$, there exists a subset $X_1$ of $X$ such that $\mu(X_1)=b$"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think nonatomic measures guarantee this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Cameron Williams mentioned, non-atomic measures satisfy this. The proof is due to Sierpinski and uses Zorn's Lemma; see this [Mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222583/a-result-of-sierpi%C5%84ski-on-non-atomic-measures) and this [Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1398683/43949).

Comment: And it's an if and only if: if a measure is atomic, then there is some subset $X_1$ such that $0<\mu(X_1)\le a$ and no measurable subset has measure $\frac{\mu(X_1)}2$.

Answer (score 1):

If the measure space is *complete*, then it contains all sets of measure zero. Since the empty set is a subset of every set, then you can always find a subset $X_1 = \emptyset \subset X$ such that your condition holds.

A less trivial example has to do with *non-atomic* measures. I refer you to the nice links given by angryavian.